# Screensaver: it doesn't start but why?

Tags: windows

On my Windows7 personal: I don't get that: sometimes I have LoL running (= running, *not* playing), 2 or 3 ssh sessions and Chrome running, and the screensaver is properly launched, my screen are turned off.

Sometimes, I go away and in the morning the screensaver was not launched. I have no correct explanation for this.

Any idea?

Comment: Flagged as off-topic, non-enterprise questions should be asked on SuperUser.

Comment: Are you sure the screensaver was not launched? What's always running when it isn't - same things you mentioned above? Certain apps can of course prevent the screensaver from launching, or the computer going into standby and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developper, and I watched all the apps. Exactly all the same apps are running. I'm wondering if Chrome, on a special URLs (launching videos or flash plugin) prevents my screensaver to launch. Seems the problem is around https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=9853

Answer (score 0):

Windows application may programmatically inform the operating system that screen saver should not be started at the moment (e.g. catching [SC_SCREENSAVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

So yes, if any of your application is in a state when it thinks running screensaver is a bad idea, it may disable temporarily it or prevent it to start. Watching full screen movies in many media player applications is a common example. A buggy appliation may